# Combine items in a list until an item containing specific text is found?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is going to be hard to explain.

I'm fetching some webpages with BeautifulSoup, and I'm trying to organize them into a list. I'm fetching only the elements on the page that have the class "text". Like this:

```
content = requests.get(url, verify=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer('p'))
filtered_soup = soup.find_all("span", {"class":["text",
                                                "indent-1"]})
line_list = [line for line in filtered_soup]
#text_list = [line.get_text() for line in filtered_soup]
```

This works great, but I'd also like to combine some of the items in the list. On the webpage, some of the items with `class="text..."` also have `id="en..."`. They technically SHOULD be the parents of the other `class="text..."` elements, but the webpage has not been set up this way.

In my "line_list" list, there is an item with both `class="text..."` and `id="en..."` elements, then there are a few items with only `class="text..."`, then there is an item with both `class="text..."` and `id="en..."` elements, and this pattern keeps repeating. Here's a way to think of it:

```
line_list = [A, a, a, a, B, b, b, C, c, c, c, c]
```

Now here's the hard part to explain. Let's say `line_list[0]` has both elements, `line_list[1-3]` only have the "class" element, and `line_list[4]` has both elements again. I'd like to iterate through `line_list` and combine the items into a single string. But when the iteration hits an item containing both "id" and "class" (i.e. `line_list[4]`), I'd like it to start creating a new string.

Or, if someone can think of a better way to do this, that'd be awesome. I was going to try to do this:

```
line_string = ''.join(line_list)
split_list = line_string.split('id="en')
```

But the `join` command complains that `line_string` contains tags, not strings.

I wonder if it'd be easier to do this with a dictionary? For example, make the elements that have both "class" and "id" the keys and the elements that only have "class" their values. It'd look like this:

```
line_dic = {A: [a, a, a], B: [b, b], C: [c, c, c, c]}
```

Here's example html if anyone would like to play with it:

```
line_list = [<span class="text 1" id="en-13987>A<span class="small-caps" style="font-variant: small-caps">A</span>,
             <span class="indent-1"><span class="indent-1-breaks">    </span><span class="text 1">a</span></span>,
             <span class="text 1">a</span>,
             <span class="text 2" id="en-13988">B<span class="small-caps" style="font-variant: small-caps">B</span>B</span>,
             <span class="indent-1"><span class="indent-1-breaks">    </span><span class="text 2">b<span class="small-caps" style="font-variant: small-caps">b</span>b</span></span>,
             <span class="text 2">b<span class="small-caps" style="font-variant: small-caps">b</span>b</span>,
             <span class="text 3" id="en-13989">C</span>,
              <span class="indent-1"><span class="indent-1-breaks">    </span><span class="text 3">c<span class="small-caps" style="font variant: small-caps">c</span>c</span></span>,
             <span class="text 3">c<span class="small-caps" style="font-variant: small-caps">c</span>c</span>,]
```

Awesome ideas, guys. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a cool one-liner, but, the following should work...:

```
text_list = []
current = []
for line in line_list:
    if line.get('id', '').startswith('en'):
        if current:
            text_list.append(' '.join(current))
            current = []
    current.append(line.text)
if current:
    text_list.append(' '.join(current))
```

For example, adding this code after a sample test-start of

```
import bs4

content = '''
<span class='text' class='indent-1' id='en00'>And one</span>
<span class='text' class='indent-1'>And two</span>
<span class='text' class='indent-1'>And three</span>
<span class='text' class='indent-1' id='en01'>And four</span>
<span class='text' class='indent-1'>And five</span>
'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content)
filtered_soup = soup.find_all("span", {"class":["text", "indent-1"]})
line_list = [line for line in filtered_soup]
```

a `for x in test_list: print(x)` will display

```
And one And two And three
And four And five
```

which seems to match the desired result.

Added: here's an arguably better-factored solution, which does however end up being more verbose:

```
def has_id_en(elem):
    return elem.get('id', '').startswith('en')

def segment(sequence, is_head):
  current = []
  for x in sequence:
      if is_head(x):
          if current:
              yield current
              current = []
      current.append(x)
  if current:
      yield current

text_list = [' '.join(e.text for e in bunch)
             for bunch in segment(line_list, has_id_en)]
```

At least, this way, the `segment` logic is reusable for similar tasks where the items in the sequence need not be bs4 objects, and/or the way to determine whether an item needs to "head" a subsequence is different than in this specific problem.

Comment: Awesome! I like this one. Although thanks for the other ones guys! They're handy tools I'll store away.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), like this:

```
import itertools

def has_id_en(elem):
    # return True if the elem has id="en..."
    ...

for is_id_en, elems in itertools.groupby(filtered_soup, has_id_en):
    if is_id_en:
        # this is the parent
        continue
    else:
        # do somthing with this group of elems
        ...
```

Comment: So you get bunch of lines, alternatively ones with and ones w/o the `id="en..."`, and you ignore the bunches **with** that `id` -- the idea is cool, but the execution seems pretty incomplete...:-)

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought about using `itertools.takewhile`, but this has the problem that it "swallows" the next "separator" element. Instead, you can try this, using only builtins:

```
def has_both(x):
    return x.isupper() # or whatever your actual condition is

line_dic = {}
last = None
for x in line_list:
    if has_both(x):
        last = x
        line_dic[last] = []
    else:
        line_dic[last].append(x)
```

Result is `{'A': ['a', 'a', 'a'], 'C': ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 'B': ['b', 'b']}`

For Python 2.7 and newer, you can also use `collections.OrderedDict` to preserve the order in which the items are inserted into the dictionary. Also, if you are expecting to see "child" elements before any "parent" element, initialize `line_dic` as `{None: []}`.

Comment: Two `has_both` items immediately one after the other will result in the first one being discarded, rather than entered in the dict with an empty sub-list as it should.  To fix, put `line_dic[last] = []` in the `if` branch, and just `line_dic[last].append(x)` in the `else` branch -- also, start `line_dic` as `{None:[]}` unless you "know" the `line_list` starts with an `has_both` item.  Lastly, using `OrderedDict` here would preserve the order of `has_both` items.

Comment: much better answer now, thanks (also edited it to fix a typo:-).